# Unable to view organizational policies of GCP organization I own

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-console

Within an organization of which I am the sole admin, I am unable to enumerate and therefore manage the organizational policies from within the GCP console.  Does anyone know why this might be and/or how I'd go about fixing it?  Any guidance as to documentation that was perhaps missed during setup, etc. would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is working now, but I'd still like to know the answer.  Apparently someone at Google added me to the administrator role (couldn't do that myself).  Other issues were then fixed by granting myself "Owner".  Not sure that's the most secure way to go about it, but am no longer "blocked."  If anyone knows what happened and how I could have fixed it, please let me know.

Comment: I would need to know what IAM roles you originally had. However, most likely you could have added the required IAM roles yourself (since you state you owned the organization). However, do not make the mistake of granting yourself all IAM roles. The organization administrator should be locked away and only used to create other IAM members with job related permissions.

Comment: Agreed and generally understood, @JohnHanley.  Just was at the point where I could do nothing.  The answer below addressed the bulk of it, but your comment is important community information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Organization Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org) includes the missing permissions `resourcemanager.organizations.get` along with `orgpolicy.constraints.list` and `orgpolicy.policies.list`.

Do note that this role is not automatically granted for being the sole user on the account, this has to be assigned via the IAM menu.

The Owner role does not have these permissions as the Owner is only limited on a Project level.